# Optimal scheduling of tasks with variable number of workers

Tags: python, algorithm, scheduled-tasks

I have tasks with known integer length of their duration. Tasks also have dependencies between them. I also have an arbitrary number of workers I can schedule those tasks on.

I would like to find an optimal schedule for them in a way that I first minimize the overall length of the execution of all tasks, and second I would like to schedule task on a worker where the most of prior dependencies have been run before, and third I would like to minimize the number of workers needed.

So if task has dependencies A, B, and C, and worker1 run A and B, worker2 run C, then I would prefer that the new task is added to worker1.

I am making a visualization for a program execution flow and tasks are in fact function calls (with known number of operations) and dependencies are data dependencies. Instead of one long linear representation I would like to visualize independent calls in parallel. I see this problem as analog to the task scheduling problem I described above.

In my first simple approach I managed to optimize for the length of overall execution, but if tasks do not have a prior dependency, it adds them to their own workers. Even if there are unused holes in existing workers. So I am not sure how to optimize for both length first and number of workers as well. Before I spend more time on this I was wondering if there is some known algorithm to solve this, even a library, I could just use.

This question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586170/how-to-optimize-makespan-of-worker-labor-to-maximum-time-usage-given-a-set-of-po) because:

- Tasks do not have due date, but dependencies.
- I would like to schedule tasks on same worker where prior dependencies were scheduled.
- There are multiple additional workers possible, not just one.

Comment: The cited duplicate has one "optional" worker, but is easily generalized to minimize the number of workers needed.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify why it is not a duplicate. Please reopen.

Comment: Okay: search for postings that schedule with constraints.  Cite what you find, update your question, and we'll get it reopened.

Comment: This now looks more like a room scheduling algorithm, in which the school wants to (a) fit the class schedule into as short a time as possible; (b) use as few rooms as possible, given `a`; (c) keep similar classes in the same room, given `a` and `b`.  You might try searching "room scheduling algorithm", as well.

Comment: A concrete example or two would help -- just tasks, dependencies, and time for each task.  Also, we should know the full assignment priorities.  For instance, you say that you would *prefer* to assign a task to a worker familiar with the dependencies, but you don't describe what trade-off keeps this from being a strict requirement.

Answer (score 1):

First, make a dependency graph; see topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) for possible detail work.

Apply [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) with the comparison flipped, which will find the longest path.  This gives you your minimum execution time and the critical path.  With this in hand, assign that critical path to a single worker.

Now, look for dependency sub-paths that include multiple dependencies in no more time than the dependency they replace.  For instance, if you have a time-line for tasks A, B, C which are needed by D, with B&C summing to less time than A, you'll start with this:

```
crit   AAAAAADDDDD
other  BBBCC
```

You can swap the two-task arc with task A, giving you a new preferential allocation:

```
worker1 BBBCC-DDDDD
worker2 AAAAAA-----
```

Does that get you started?